# Pluripolarity of non-generic Laurent polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

Let us consider the Laurent polynomials on $(\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\})^m$. By Bertini's theorem, for a generic system $(f_1, \ldots, f_k)$, its zero set becomes a complex submanifold of codimension $k$. My question is: Non-generic Laurent polynomials can be a pluripolar set in the space of Laurent polynomials? Here we can identify the space of Laurent polynomials with $\mathbb{C}^{d_{n}}$, where $d_{n}$ is the dimension of the polynomial space.